# SecurityException when running android app on phone

Tags: java, android, exception, emulation

I am testing my app on an external phone for the first time... It works perfectly on the emulator.  My external device is a Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge.

I cannot begin to figure out where the error is because when I run it in debug mode and put a breakpoint at the first line of the onCreate() of the launching activity, it throws the error before it even gets there.

Although a solution would be great, I'd really like to know the steps I need to take to find the root cause of this and problem solve it.

Thanks

```
Launching application: com.projects.fbgrecojr.vamoose/com.projects.fbgrecojr.vamoose.LoginActivity.
    DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start  -n "com.projects.fbgrecojr.vamoose/com.projects.fbgrecojr.vamoose.LoginActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
    Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.projects.fbgrecojr.vamoose/.LoginActivity }
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.projects.fbgrecojr.vamoose/.LoginActivity } from null (pid=31173, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10224
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerNative.java:2586)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:768)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:307)
    at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:102)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:255)
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.projects.fbgrecojr.vamoose" >

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".UserActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_user" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AdminActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_admin" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AdminSettings"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_admin_settings" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ContactsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_contacts" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AddUser"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_specific_contact" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".User"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_user" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HistoryActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_history" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CalendarActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_calendar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AboutActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_about" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please post your manifest. It would appear that you have blocked `LoginActivity` from being exported.

Comment: I posted the AndroidActivity.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your manifest you should specify the activity that should be launched on startup using an `intent-filter`:

```
<activity
  android:name=".LoginActivity"
  android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The problem here is that without an `intent-filter` the activities by default are not exported ([docs on android:exported](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exported)) and can be started only by components of the same application or applications with the same user ID.

Comment: Awesome! This worked! Not whenever I run it it's waiting for debugger even though it's not in debug mode so if you have a quick fix for this awesome otherwise i'll troubleshoot it.

Comment: @Frank: relating to debugger screen, in your phone select "None" in "Developer Options"->"Debug"->"Choose debug application"